# Tire Damage Requires Replacement?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

[image]

Got some curb damage to this tire, but haven’t experienced any deflation.  Is this something that will require replacing the tire?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like sidewall damage. However some tire shops can repair this, fill in the hole then bake the tire in oven and it's done.

Here I will copy my answer from another question:

Sidewall damages are most dangerous one. The tires weakest spot is Sidewall. If you drive with this tire at high speed it can start to wobble and pop out of nowhere. Since it won't be a tiny hole that will lose air gradually, but a serious pop you might lose control and crash. Just change the tire.
If you don't fix the tire you should replace it.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell from the image angle, but if the cords or plies are exposed at the bottom of that cut, then YES, it needs to be replaced.